# nstableview add row as title and set consecutive number

Tags: arrays, macos, cocoa, swift3, nstableview

i have this tableview with two columns (First name, Second Name)
i fill the tableview with data from an array.
now i would like to realize, that i can add a "normal" row (person) and a row like a tile.

For example:

row 1: male persons
row 2: Max | Mustermann
row 3: Peter | Düllen

for that i tried to fill my array like this:

```
Data(firstName: "male persons", secondName: "", typ: "titel")
Data(firstname: "Max", secondName: "Mustermann", typ: "person")
Data(firstname: "Peter", secondName: "Düllen", typ: "person")
```

it works but is this the correct way to set a row like a title?

Second question:
each row should get in another column a consecutive number.
at the moment i realized that with the row number. but now the problem is, that the title rows should not get an consecutive number.

Little example (at the end of line are the numbers which i would like to realize):

```
Data(firstName: "male persons", secondName: "", typ: "titel") []
Data(firstname: "Max", secondName: "Mustermann", typ: "person") [1]
Data(firstname: "Peter", secondName: "Düllen", typ: "person") [2]

Data(firstName: "male persons", secondName: "", typ: "titel") []
Data(firstname: "Max", secondName: "Mustermann", typ: "person") [3]
Data(firstname: "Peter", secondName: "Düllen", typ: "person")[4]
```

how can i solve this situation?
i hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can populate the table view like you want. Your solution will work fine. Just make sure `Data` is not part of the “model” layer of your app. (The “model” layer should not be aware of how the data is displayed to the user, so it shouldn’t be aware of those title rows.)

There are other ways to do it. For instance, you could have an array of sections:

```
struct Person {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
}

struct Section {
    let title: String
    let people: [Person]
}

let person1 = Person(firstName: "Max", lastName: "Mustermann")
let person2 = Person(firstName: "Peter", lastName: "Düllen")
let section1 = Section(title: "male persons", people: [person1, person2])

let person3 = Person(firstName: "Max", lastName: "Mustermann")
let person4 = Person(firstName: "Peter", lastName: "Düllen")
let section2 = Section(title: "male persons", people: [person3, person4])

var sections = [section1, section2]

// Now implement the table view data source and
// delegate methods to display the sections array.
```

In this solution, `Person` can be a part of the app’s “model” layer.